# On Visual Studio Emulator, Mobile has no access to laptop networks

Tags: c#, xamarin, ssms, emulation, database-connection

I'm working on a Xamarin app and need to connect to a database on a server on my local network. I can connect to the database using the server explorer in Visual Studio, but the connection string I obtain from there does not appear to work. "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." is the error I get. This is the string I use to connect to the server. Obviously, I substituted data with fakes: `Data Source=134.2.512.6\\instance;Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=user;Password=youshallnotpass;`

`MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Constants.connectionString);` is how I connect.

Is it possible that it's because my emulation can't connect to the same networks as my laptop?

Comment: SSMS and MySQL don't mix; what RDBMS are you really using as you seem confused.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Management Studio, I am trying to access my data from an emulator. I followed numerous tutorials all featuring MySqlConnection and they all worked. @Larnu

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like application for **SQL Server**, peet214, and it has **nothing** to do with MySQL. If you're trying to connect to SSMS with a MySQL Connection you've done *very* wrong. You need to connect to SQL Server with the SQL Server drivers.

Comment: How can I achieve this? @Larnu I am quite new to mobile development. I've tried numerous things but can't seem to solve anything. The latest tutorial I've followed has been this one. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vx8OnFoPGco)

Comment: it is a **horrible** idea to try to connect directly to a remote db from a mobile client.

Comment: @Jason its a private app ment for personal use. Does this still matter then?

Comment: is it only going to deployed on a local network?  That's more reasonable.  If it is going to be exposed to the internet, then your db server is at high risk by doing this.